# Serializers.validated_data fields got changed with source value in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create an api, where user can create programs and add rules to them. Rules has to be executed in order of priority. I am using Django rest framework to achieve this and I am trying to achieve this using Serializer without using ModelSerializer. Provide your solution using serializers.Serializer class

One program can have many rules and one rule can be in many programs. So, I am using many_to_many relationship and also I want the user to change the order of rules in a program, to achieve this I am using a through table called Priority, where I keep track of relationship between a rule and a program using priority field

**models.py**

```
class Program(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    rules = models.ManyToManyField(Rule, through='Priority')

class Rule(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    rule = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class Priority(models.Model):
    program = models.ForeignKey(Program, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rule = models.ForeignKey(Rule, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    priority = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Priority, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class RuleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True)
    rule = serializers.CharField(max_length=256)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Rule.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.description = validated_data.get('description', instance.description)
        instance.rule = validated_data.get('rule', instance.rule)
        instance.save()
        return instance

class PrioritySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    rule_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='rule.id')
    rule_name = serializers.CharField(source='rule.name')
    rule_rule = serializers.CharField(source='rule.rule')
    priority = serializers.IntegerField()

class ProgramSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=32)
    description = serializers.CharField(style={'base_template': 'textarea.html'})
    rules = PrioritySerializer(source='priority_set', many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        rules_data = validated_data.pop('rules')
        program_obj = Program.objects.create(**validated_data)

        priority = 0
        for rule in rules_data:
            rule_obj = Rule.objects.get(pk=rule.rule_id)
            priority += 1
            Priority.objects.create(program=program_obj, rule=rule_obj, priority=priority)

        return program_obj
```

**views.py**

```
class ProgramList(APIView):
    """
    List all programs, or create a new program.
    """
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        programs = Program.objects.all()
        serializers = ProgramSerializer(programs, many=True)
        return Response(serializers.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = ProgramSerializer(data=request.data, partial=True)
        print(serializer.initial_data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

When I make a get request to **http://localhost:8000/api/programs/**, I got this response

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "some",
        "description": "hahah",
        "rules": [
            {
                "rule_id": 3,
                "rule_name": "DAIEA",
                "rule_rule": "date,and,invoice,equal,amount",
                "priority": 1
            },
            {
                "rule_id": 2,
                "rule_name": "DAIEA",
                "rule_rule": "date,and,invoice,equal,amount",
                "priority": 2
            },
            {
                "rule_id": 1,
                "rule_name": "DAI=A",
                "rule_rule": "date,and,invoice,equal,amount",
                "priority": 3
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "DAI=AS",
        "description": "Date and Invoice equal Amount Sumif",
        "rules": []
    },
]
```

I got list of rules under rules field, but when I make post request with this **request.data** to create a new program with rules with the help of rule.id,

**Post data**:

```
{
    "name": "DAI=AS",
    "description": "Date and Invoice equal Amount Sumif",
    "rules": [
        {
            "rule_id": 1
        },
        {
            "rule_id": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

After the serialization process, validated_data contains priority_set field instead of rules field, like below

```
{
    'name': 'DAI=AS', 
    'description': 'Date and Invoice equal Amount Sumif', 
    'priority_set': [
        OrderedDict([('rule', {'id': 1})]), 
        OrderedDict([('rule', {'id': 2})])
     ]
}
```

I don't want the serializer to change rules to priority_set

And also, I am getting list of OrderedDict in priority_set, instead I need dictionary of rule objects

This is what I want after serialization process,

```
{
    "name": "DAI=AS",
    "description": "Date and Invoice equal Amount Sumif",
    "rules": [
        {
            "rule_id": 1
        },
        {
            "rule_id": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

The fields in validated data is renamed with the source attribute. You can use the renamed attribute in `create` method of serializer.

For nested serializers, seems the validated data contains `OrderedDict`. You can convert it to regular `Dict`, and can get the rule id.

```
class ProgramSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=32)
    description = serializers.CharField(style={'base_template': 'textarea.html'})
    rules = PrioritySerializer(source='priority_set', many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        rules_data = validated_data.pop('priority_set')
        program_obj = Program.objects.create(**validated_data)

        priority = 0
        for rule in rules_data:
            rule_obj = Rule.objects.get(pk=dict(rule)["rule"]["id"])
            priority += 1
            Priority.objects.create(program=program_obj, rule=rule_obj, priority=priority)

        return program_obj
```

**Solution 2:**

You can make `rules` with source name `priority_set` as `read_only` and can extract it from request data.

```
class ProgramSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=32)
    description = serializers.CharField(style={'base_template': 'textarea.html'})
    rules = PrioritySerializer(source='priority_set', many=True, read_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        rules_data = self.context["request"].data["rules"]
        program_obj = Program.objects.create(**validated_data)

        priority = 0
        for rule in rules_data:
            rule_obj = Rule.objects.get(pk=rule["rule_id"])
            priority += 1
            Priority.objects.create(program=program_obj, rule=rule_obj, priority=priority)

        return program_obj
```

You will need to pass request context to serializer

```
serializer = ProgramSerializer(data=request.data, partial=True, context={"request": request})
```

**Solution 3:**

Add `related_name` in `program` Foreign key in `Priority` model.

```
program = models.ForeignKey(Program, related_name="rule", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Rename `rules` field in `ProgramSerializer` to something else e.g. `rule`, and remove source.

```
class ProgramSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=32)
    description = serializers.CharField(style={'base_template': 'textarea.html'})
    rule = PrioritySerializer(many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        rules_data = validated_data.pop('rule')
        program_obj = Program.objects.create(**validated_data)

        priority = 0
        for rule in rules_data:
            rule_obj = Rule.objects.get(pk=dict(rule)["rule"]["id"])
            priority += 1
            Priority.objects.create(program=program_obj, rule=rule_obj, priority=priority)

        return program_obj
```

Now you will be able to post and retrieve data with `rule` key. You can rename it something else as appropriate.

Comment: I think solution 1 is better than solution 2, if we pass request object as context, we are not making use of PrioritySerializer to serialize the rules object? correct me if I am wrong.

And is it possible to change the priority_set name, by using related_name='rules' in many_to_many like this, rules = models.ManyToManyField(Rule, related_name='rules', through='Priority')

Comment: Right! in that way, you will need to include `related_name` in `program` Foreign Key in `Priority` model, as you have to access it through `Program` model object. But, this `related_name` should be different from `rules` otherwise it will conflict. I am adding 3rd solution.

Comment: Yeah, I tried adding related_name='rules', it created a conflict as you said and thanks for 3rd solution